# Why isn't MID() a valid identifier in my sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the wrong in my query?

```
select MID(First_Name,1,3) As 'Short Name' from employee;
```

The error shows `ORA-00904: "MID": invalid identifier`

Comment: I don't know anything about oracle, but based on the (very) helpful error message, I would assume `MID` isn't a built-in function. (Perhaps you're looking for `SUBSTR`?)

Comment: you need to use SUBSTR function.

Comment: You should choose correct answers if they helped you. You're not giving people who answer your questions any credit at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to get a cut down version of a string of text, I'd recommend using `SUBSTR`

`SUBSTR( string, start_position, substring_length)`

for example:

`select SUBSTR(First_Name,1,3) As 'Short Name' from employee;`

Answer (score 3):

**`MID()`** is supported by MySQL, but not by MS SQL Server or Oracle. This is why you're getting an error.

Use **`SUBSTR(First_name,1,3)`** instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur comment

Answer (score 2):

Your question has the answer in it :)

*ORA-00904: "MID": invalid identifier*

Oracle is quite smart most of time in returning the meaningful errors, there is no such function as MID in oracle.